# How to visualize categorical variables using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, categorical-data

I executed the code below to visualize my categorical variable:

```
p3 <- ggplot(combi %>% 
               group_by(Item_Type) %>% 
               summary(count = n())) + 
  geom_bar(aes(Item_Fat_Content, count), stat = "Identity", fill = "coral1") + 
  xlab("") + 
  geom_label(aes(Item_Fat_Content, count, label = count), vjust = 0.5 ) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  ggtitle("Item Type")
```

It threw me an error stating:

> Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by
>   `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class table

Comment: replace `summary` with `summarize`

Comment: reproducible example please.

Comment: @Ankith B Thalanki, could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Will make sure my future questions will be short and clear to the point. Thank You @Artem

Answer (score 1):

As Pogibas commented:

1. substitute  `summary` to `summarize`. Please see the code below (with the `combi` data frame simulation);
2. check the data you are providing into aesthetics (I put `left_join` to make a code executable).

Please see the code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
n <- 10
m <- 3
combi <- data.frame(
  Item_Type = sample(letters[1:m], n, replace = TRUE),
  Item_Fat_Content = abs(rnorm(n))
)

ggplot(combi %>% 
               group_by(Item_Type) %>% 
               summarise(count = n()) %>% left_join(combi)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(Item_Fat_Content, count), stat = "Identity", fill = "coral1") + 
  xlab("") + 
  geom_label(aes(Item_Fat_Content, count, label = count), vjust = 0.5 ) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  ggtitle("Item Type")
```

Output:
[image: graphics]